# Can't install ruby on MacOS Mojave

Tags: macos, ruby

I have a new MBP running Mojave and am trying to install ruby v2.6.5. I've installed Homebrew and am trying to install ruby via [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/), which uses ruby-build.

The installation keeps hanging with the message `ruby-build: using readline from homebrew`. I've found a few other people on the internet with similar issues but no real fixes yet. I'm wondering if anyone here has encountered this and found a fix?

```
mbp:dotfiles $ asdf plugin-add ruby https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby.git
mbp:dotfiles $ asdf install ruby 2.6.5
Downloading ruby-build...
Cloning into 'ruby-build-source'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 1, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Total 9941 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 9940
Receiving objects: 100% (9941/9941), 2.10 MiB | 8.70 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (6477/6477), done.
Note: switching to 'v20191004'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:

  git switch -c <new-branch-name>

Or undo this operation with:

  git switch -

Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false

HEAD is now at da8e0b4 Bump version to v20191004
ruby-build: using openssl from homebrew
Downloading ruby-2.6.5.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.6/ruby-2.6.5.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.6.5...
ruby-build: using readline from homebrew
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you did not provide full error message.

Possible reason is that you are trying to install ruby with incompartible openssl version. Check these links, maybe it will help:

- https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1353
- https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby/issues/157

To solve this you may need to update ruby asdf plugin `asdf plugin update ruby`